# Scroll bar does not appear in Silverlight App

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I doing a Silverlight 4 App.

I have mainpage.xaml, inside it i use **navigation frame control** to navigate to child pages.
When **minimizing** the page, scrollbar does not appear. As well at maximized, when the content exceeds height .the vertical scrol bar does not appear. i have used scrollviewer,but nothing happens

Below shown is my Mainpage.xaml code

```
<UserControl xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"  x:Class="Life_Centre_App.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"         
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="1024" d:DesignWidth="768" xmlns:dxr="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/ribbon" xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core" xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars" Opacity="1">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" dx:ThemeManager.ApplyApplicationTheme="True">
       <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <navigation:Frame x:Name="navframe_content"  Margin="0,159,0,0" />
            </ScrollViewer></Grid></UserControl>
```

Is this the way to approach this?

Need help on this!

Answer (score 1):

You should set `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` properties of `ScrollViewer` to a non-auto value i.e. a fixed value. Once your navigation frame control's height exceeds that height you will see scrollbar.

Comment: well this worked. but when i minimize i don't get scroll bar..i tried puttin minheight n minwidth value..anyidea?

Comment: minimize what, the browser window?